# R: Reshaping irregular time series data without explicit unique dates

Tags: r, reshape

I am studying ways of reading monthly time-series data that isn't neatly organised in wide format with 'date' columns and 'data' columns. For example, this spreadsheet from [SEMI](http://www.sia-online.org/clientuploads/directory/IndustryStatistics/GSR1976-June%202012.xls) has blocks of data organised by month and region, but the years are separated and in non-contiguous blocks, with the year in YYYY form as a header preceding each block.

[image: non-contiguous data]

My aim is to convert this data to a contiguous block with the monthly date in column 1 and the regional data in columns 2:6. After exporting this spreadsheet as a tab-separated file (I find that both `gdata` and `XLConnect` have problems with merged cells of the kind you can seen in the screenshot) I read it in and took a subset, which is the source of the `dput` below.

I have taken the approach of first stripping out empty rows using something like this:

```
mydf <- mydf[which(grepl("^$", mydf$January) == FALSE),]
```

then add a label in the Region column for the rows that have the year - conveniently this always appears in the second ('January') column.

```
mydf[which(nchar(mydf$January) == 4) ,'Region'] <- 'mydate'
```

The next step is to fill the columns from January to December in these 'year' rows with a monthly date. I figured that once I had a unique date for each month I would be able to process it using `ddply` or something.

```
mydf[which(mydf$Region == 'mydate'), 2:13] <- apply(mydf[which(mydf$Region == 'mydate'), 2:13], 1, function(x) as.character(seq(as.Date(paste(x['January'],"-01-01", sep = "")), as.Date(paste(x['January'],"-12-01", sep = "")), by = 'month')))
```

This hasn't quite worked as I expected as the `apply` function isn't generating dates in the way I had hoped for - they are not in sequence. I would much appreciate either (a) a specific fix for `apply` step or (b) pointers alternative approaches that may be simpler or easier.

Data and code below:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Region = c("", "Americas", "Europe", "Japan",
"Asia Pacific", "Worldwide", "", "", "Americas", "Europe", "Japan",
"Asia Pacific", "Worldwide", "", "", "Americas", "Europe", "Japan",
"Asia Pacific", "Worldwide", "", "", "", "Americas", "Europe",
"Japan", "Asia Pacific", "Worldwide", "", "", "Americas", "Europe",
"Japan", "Asia Pacific", "Worldwide"), January = c("1980", "413136",
"189577", "34033", "39868", "676614", "", "1981", "445504", "277290",
"33970", "44642", "801406", "", "1982", "445300", "226274", "34404",
"44989", "750967", "", "January", "1983", "457604", "232443",
"34326", "46247", "770621", "", "1984", "731009", "285740", "205644",
"85426", "1307820"), February = c("", "423748", "234818", "35104",
"42398", "736069", "", "", "440225", "274526", "33795", "44005",
"792550", "", "", "438332", "226806", "33359", "44020", "742517",
"", "February", "", "457899", "233560", "32604", "46184", "770247",
"", "", "790963", "307735", "381282", "102791", "1582770"), March = c("",
"436152", "281353", "34456", "46555", "798516", "", "", "434628",
"267259", "33709", "45206", "780802", "", "", "441313", "235612",
"32380", "43600", "752905", "", "March", "", "459498", "234986",
"31544", "48178", "774206", "", "", "856970", "339674", "574527",
"118091", "1889262"), April = c("", "455673", "288710", "34451",
"48585", "827419", "", "", "443285", "264405", "34823", "47192",
"789705", "", "", "465613", "246425", "33618", "46274", "791930",
"", "April", "", "484299", "243867", "32719", "52333", "813218",
"", "", "909873", "364465", "627400", "126954", "2028693"), May = c("",
"474441", "297343", "35092", "51102", "857977", "", "", "451221",
"255887", "35499", "48459", "791065", "", "", "487738", "249522",
"34339", "47727", "819325", "", "May", "", "507807", "246136",
"34708", "59300", "847950", "", "", "969553", "382706", "655862",
"133455", "2141576"), June = c("", "475552", "299427", "35743",
"51440", "862162", "", "", "453152", "242889", "35798", "48147",
"779986", "", "", "488564", "241273", "34360", "48871", "813068",
"", "June", "", "528620", "246710", "37345", "62910", "875586",
"", "", "991274", "388697", "672773", "135550", "2188294"), July = c("",
"473007", "302075", "37771", "51027", "863880", "", "", "454387",
"231097", "35402", "47468", "768353", "", "", "480702", "229555",
"33915", "49112", "793284", "", "July", "", "543063", "241211",
"40403", "66658", "891335", "", "", "1005742", "395852", "683854",
"138853", "2224302"), August = c("", "462125", "294497", "37628",
"49773", "844023", "", "", "450648", "213017", "34363", "46614",
"744642", "", "", "472486", "215763", "32866", "48620", "769734",
"", "August", "", "565034", "236353", "42524", "66853", "910763",
"", "", "1010739", "393337", "691731", "141101", "2236908"),
    September = c("", "461968", "295501", "37310", "50280", "845059",
    "", "", "459276", "215403", "33801", "47297", "755777", "",
    "", "475729", "219643", "33083", "47540", "775994", "", "September",
    "", "593019", "244979", "44108", "70242", "952348", "", "",
    "1035725", "408658", "698992", "141944", "2285320"), October = c("",
    "459862", "296522", "36399", "51220", "844003", "", "", "465096",
    "218792", "34168", "47369", "765424", "", "", "467151", "225828",
    "33667", "47890", "774536", "", "October", "", "618854",
    "259807", "47622", "71345", "997628", "", "", "1033560",
    "421043", "710563", "140154", "2305320"), November = c("",
    "456832", "296283", "35769", "50531", "839415", "", "", "467288",
    "232593", "35039", "47415", "782335", "", "", "461950", "237117",
    "35672", "47285", "782024", "", "November", "", "641864",
    "275099", "50371", "72095", "1039428", "", "", "1008836",
    "441652", "732948", "133861", "2317297"), December = c("",
    "460343", "291348", "35781", "48298", "835771", "", "", "460574",
    "231461", "35971", "47173", "775179", "", "", "462919", "235861",
    "36251", "47974", "783006", "", "December", "", "672533",
    "276525", "54603", "74717", "1078379", "", "", "982210",
    "442448", "731546", "132982", "2289187")), .Names = c("Region",
"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), row.names = 29:63, class = "data.frame")

mydf <- mydf[which(grepl("^$", mydf$January) == FALSE),] # remove rows with nothing in the January column
mydf[which(nchar(mydf$January) == 4) ,'Region'] <- 'mydate' # add a row label for 'year' rows

mydf[which(mydf$Region == 'mydate'), 2:13] <- apply(mydf[which(mydf$Region == 'mydate'), 2:13], 1, function(x) as.character(seq(as.Date(paste(x['January'],"-01-01", sep = "")), as.Date(paste(x['January'],"-12-01", sep = "")), by = 'month')))
```

Comment: Can you post what you want the output to look like? I'm not clear about what type of reshaping you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the following approach:

First, I converted your file to a CSV, then read the lines in. I used `grep()` to find "Americas", which is the first line in each set. I manually entered the start and end years, but some `grep` could probably be used there too.

```
temp = readLines("GSR1976-June 2012.csv")
START = grep("Americas", temp)
YEARS = 1976:2012
```

After that, I created a list of `data.frame`s, one for each year.

```
temp1 = lapply(1:length(YEARS), 
               function(x) read.csv("GSR1976-June 2012.csv",
                                    header=FALSE, skip=START[x]-1,
                                    nrows=5))
names(temp1) = YEARS
```

Then, I combined them into one `data.frame` and did some cleanup.

```
temp2 = do.call(rbind, temp1)
names(temp2) = c("region", "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
                 "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")
temp2$year = rep(YEARS, each=5)
```

You don't specify what type of reshaping you wanted to do, but if you wanted to go from wide to long, the easiest way is with the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
temp3 = melt(temp2, id.vars=c("region", "year"))
list(head(temp3), tail(temp3))
# [[1]]
#         region year variable  value
# 1     Americas 1976      jan     NA
# 2       Europe 1976      jan     NA
# 3        Japan 1976      jan     NA
# 4 Asia Pacific 1976      jan     NA
# 5    Worldwide 1976      jan     NA
# 6     Americas 1977      jan 195638
# 
# [[2]]
#            region year variable    value
# 2215    Worldwide 2011      dec 23832532
# 2216     Americas 2012      dec       NA
# 2217       Europe 2012      dec       NA
# 2218        Japan 2012      dec       NA
# 2219 Asia Pacific 2012      dec       NA
# 2220    Worldwide 2012      dec       NA
```

Then, for the output that it *sounds* like you're looking for, use `dcast()`:

```
temp4 = dcast(temp3, year + variable ~ region)
head(temp4)
#   year variable Americas Asia Pacific Europe Japan Worldwide
# 1 1976      jan       NA           NA     NA    NA        NA
# 2 1976      feb       NA           NA     NA    NA        NA
# 3 1976      mar   178295        16761  55602 10805    261463
# 4 1976      apr   178961        16513  60959 11589    268022
# 5 1976      may   187076        17396  62329 12435    279235
# 6 1976      jun   193675        17712  61676 14411    287475
```

Comment: @ttmaccer, I never use it for my own work, but I find that I'm driven crazy by almost every Excel file I receive from someone else. Colored cells, merged cells, cells with hard line breaks in them, sheets with the user's scratch calculations *all over the place*.... Uggh....

Comment: Thanks, educational and I was able to adapt it with no problems. I too like the use of `lapply` to read the text file in chunks. Obvious now I think of it, but it didn't occur to me until I saw your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xlsReadWrite` and `reshape2`

```
 library(xlsReadWrite)
 tdata<-read.xls('GSR1976-June 2012.xls',stringsAsFactors=F)
 tdata[85,2]<-1987 # fix for missing year
 tdata[228,2]<-2007 # fix for missing year
 year.marker<-c(grep('^[[:digit:]]{4}$',tdata[,2]),270)

 temp.df<-NULL

 for(i in seq_along(year.marker)[-length(year.marker)]){
   dum.df<-cbind(tdata[year.marker[i],2],tdata[(year.marker[i]+1):(year.marker[i+1]-2),])
   temp.df<-rbind(temp.df,dum.df)
 }

 names(temp.df)<-c('year','region',month.name)

 df1<-temp.df[!temp.df[,'region']=='',]
 library(reshape2)
 df2<-melt(df1, id.vars=c("region", "year"))
```

Comment: Add a dcast in there too and you will be done, I think. (No grave jumping accusations will be made). +1

Comment: I'm just giving you a hard time, by the way... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a few problems with xlsReadWrite but it was still useful.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned data set can easily be processed directly from the Excel file using **XLConnect** like this:

```
require(XLConnect)
require(reshape2)

# Load Excel workbook
wb = loadWorkbook("~/Downloads/GSR1976-June 2012.xls")

# Read data from 1st worksheet, starting at row 7 with predefined column types
data = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1, startRow = 7, 
    colTypes = c("character", rep("numeric", 12)))
# Rename first column and keep month names
colnames(data)[1] = "Region"
months = names(data)[-1]

# The data of merged cells (years) is in the first cell of the merged region
years = ifelse(is.na(data$Region), data$January, NA)
idx = !is.na(years)

# Replicate year information to form a new column 'Year'
data$Year = rep(years[idx], times = diff(c(which(idx), length(years) + 1)))

# Remove any rows where 'Region' is missing (^= non-data rows)
data = data[!is.na(data$Region), ]

# Reshape (wide --> long)
data = melt(data, measure.vars = months, variable.name = "Month")
```

Comment: Thanks for this Martin, always good to see an example straight from the horse's mouth. I am a frequent user of XLConnect but seldom take advantage of the additional arguments - maybe I should do that more.